# RECURSIVE query for Postgres on a single table

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I want to create one RECURSIVE query on a single table in Postgres, which is basically base on Parent and child.

Here is the **demo table** employee with data

```
id     parentid   managerid   status
------------------------------------
3741    [null]      1709        7    
3742     3741       1709        12    
3749     3742       1709        12    
3900     3749       1709        4
```

1) If **Status = 12** then the result will be, the data which has **status = 12** and all the **parents** of that particular node.

The expected result will be :

```
 id     parentid   managerid   status
--------------------------------------
 3741   [null]      1709        7    
 3742    3741       1709        12    
 3749    3742       1709        12
```

For that I have tried the query which is given below is working fine and giving proper result, even if I change the status value than also its working fine.

```
WITH RECURSIVE nodes AS (
      SELECT s1.id, case when s1.parentid=s1.id then null else s1.parentid end parentid,s1.managerid, s1.status
        FROM employees s1 WHERE id IN 
        (SELECT employees.id  FROM employees WHERE 
              "employees"."status" = 12 AND "employees"."managerid" = 1709)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT s2.id, case when s2.parentid=s2.id then null else s2.parentid end parentid,s2.managerid, s2.status
        FROM employees s2 JOIN nodes ON s2.id = nodes.parentid
)
SELECT distinct nodes.id, nodes.parentid, nodes.managerid, nodes.status  
      FROM nodes ORDER BY nodes.id ASC NULLS FIRST;
```

2) If **Status != 12** then the result will be, only all the **parents** of that particular node.

The expected result will be :

```
 id     parentid   managerid   status
--------------------------------------
 3741   [null]      1709        7
```

I want the query for status not equal some value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT * FROM tablename
  WHERE status != 12
  UNION
  SELECT t.* 
  FROM tablename t INNER JOIN cte c
  ON c.parentid = t.id
)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cte;
```

For more refer the Demo: [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rH56KyeyNTE3Azd2XTzCqh/11)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple solution but I think it should work for smaller sets of data

```sql
  SELECT * FROM employee
  WHERE 
    status=12
    OR id IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT parentId FROM employee WHERE status=12
    )
`
```

Comment: It won't work because the status value may vary. Your query is giving result which is proper only for status = 12, it's not working proper even i keep status = 4 in your query.

Comment: I am actually using the same status twice in the query. Please confirm both are updated everytime

Comment: yes I have updated at both place. for more information refer [link](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/index). We need working flow like that. In this link the demo is provided, we want to filter on particular column as shown in link. and i actually need the query to apply filter on column which is applied in demo..

Answer (score 0):

With this recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
  select * from tablename
  where status = 12
  union all
  select t.* 
  from tablename t inner join cte c
  on c.parentid = t.id
)
select distinct * from cte;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rH56KyeyNTE3Azd2XTzCqh/1).
Results:

```
| id   | parentid | managerid | status |
| ---- | -------- | --------- | ------ |
| 3741 |          | 1709      | 7      |
| 3742 | 3741     | 1709      | 12     |
| 3749 | 3742     | 1709      | 12     |
```

Comment: Why? Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rH56KyeyNTE3Azd2XTzCqh/2 It returns all rows because of status = 4.

Comment: If status !=12 then the result should be the same which is given description point no 2.

Comment: What is the logic for this? Do you want it to be hardcoded?

Comment: You can refer working demo in [https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/index](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/index). Apply any filter using not equal to and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS
(
 SELECT *
 FROM tablename
 WHERE status = 12
 UNION
 SELECT t.*
 FROM tablename t
 INNER JOIN cte c ON c.Id = t.parentid
)
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename t
LEFT JOIN cte c on t.id=c.id
WHERE c.id IS NULL
ORDER BY id ASC NULLS FIRST;
```

Comment: Hi Vijay, Welcome to SO :) While this answer may solve the original problem but it is [always better to describe the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) how exactly it is solving the problem :)